# Как лучше всего передать сотрудникам компании заказчика разработанное ios приложение?

Tags: ios, apple

Наша фирма создала по заказу другой фирмы приложение для ios. Мы залили в апстор, но его отклонили, так как оно узконаправленное (это приложение для склада, где грузчик сканирует товары и забивает их в базу). В поддержке порекомендовали b2b вариант. Но вот тут возникло много вопросов. 
Если я правильно понял удобнее всего enterprise лицензия. Но вопрос в том кто должен её приобрести разработчик или заказчик?
А вариант ad hoc как я понял подойдёт для developer лицензии, но тут ещё более непонятно. Надо предварительно знать все apple id тех, кто будет пользоваться приложением и вносить их заранее при создании provisioning profile - и потом (хотя может я неправильно понял) изменить их нельзя. Плюс ограничение в 100 устройств.
Я ещё где-то читал, что есть способ скомпилировать ipa и plist и выложить на сервер, а потом сгенерировать ссылку. Но тут вообще я не уверен, что это сработает.

Посоветуете как лучше всего передать заказчику разработанное приложение, чтобы его сотрудники могли легко его себе установить.

Comment: `ipa` и `plist` ваше верное решение, бодаться с яблочниками это излишние и неблагодарное дело, как и соблюдение их требований и лицензий.. :)

Comment: не думал что Эбола до такой степени д****. ну серьезно. Не пойму. и что что приложение узконаправленное. Им места жалко или что? Сколько приложений которые делать что-то одно и ничего же. эбола еще больше упала в моих глазах.

P.S. переделайте под андроид и таких проблем не будет вообще)

Comment: Гламурный грузчик с айфоном. Постапокалиптическое какое-то видение. :-)

Comment: @Tsyklop как раз изначально делали под Андроид, но оказалось что им только под айфон.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 это немецкие грузчики, так что как раз)

Comment: @cheerful_weasel Вы спокойно можете говорить что все претензии к эболе)

Comment: @NewView а где бы узнать подробнее как это делается?

Comment: В Гугле конечно 'hosting apple application' например спросите.

Comment: @NewView я пробовал гуглить, но мне на данном этапе непонятен процесс создания ipa. Provisioning profile как создавать? В смысле при его создании надо в Distribution ставить appstore галочку или что-то другое?

Comment: Вот детали не подскажу, но кажеться манифест надо править в ручную, меняя адрес АПП сторе на свой. Где то встречал подробный how-to, вспомню адрес, кину ссылку..

Comment: И кстати, по любому можно загрузить приложение в девелопмент режиме, через сафари кажеться, с предупреждениями естественно. [вот](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808598-iOS-Creating-an-Installation-Link-for-Your-Enterprise-App) и [вот](https://m.vk.com/pages?oid=-76603052&p=Как_установить_приложение_на_iPhone%3F)

Comment: @NewView решил попробовать с тем профилем что для appstore. И на этапе прикрепления provisioning profile написало, что он не для in-house

Comment: [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6) посмотрите, там в картинках :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вот то что вам нужно:

[Distribute Apps in Volume](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/)

Позволяет легально и без проблемно устанавливать программы **для других организаций**.

---

2. Альтернатива - [Apple Developer Enterprise Program - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

Покупать программу лучше от имени заказчика, иначе в будущем могут быть проблемы с добавлением пользователей (особенно если вы закончите совместную работу).

Вот статьи про практический опыт, хоть и немного устаревшие, но могут пригодится:

[Создаем свое AppStore для распространения по программе iOS Enterprise Distribution](https://habr.com/company/naumen/blog/205780/)

[Как распространять iOS приложения минуя AppStore](https://habr.com/post/160087/)

Comment: А можно подробнее про Distribute Apps in Volume? Это надо отдельный аккаунт? Это платно? И каким образом компилируется приложение - какой provisioning profile, файл ipa создаётся?

Comment: @cheerful_weasel Это платно, но вроде недорого. Актуальной цены я найти не смог (скорее всего при регистрации надо указать тип аккаунта). Приложение компилируется и загружается в itunesconnect как обычно, но не требует одобрения от Apple. Вот еще нашел старую презентацию от Apple (они ее с тех пор не обновили): https://download.developer.apple.com/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_311__building_and_distributing_custom_b2b_apps_for_ios.pdf

Comment: VPP и ABM для России не доступны, список можно посмотреть на сайте ABM (а VPP с конца 2019 года перестала существовать).

Comment: Для создания приложении для VPP подходит любая стандартная учетка разработчика Apple за 99 баксов. Проверка приложения делается, но чуть-чуть более слабая. Одно не до конца доделанное приложение (был второй экран пустой с заглушкой-текстовой меткой и еще кое-что) для VPP сначала одобрили совсем без проблем, а потом к обновленной версии докопались. В итоге "поругался" с ними в переписке, написал, что это для ABM, типа не ваше собачье дело - нам так надо, для себя только размещаем. Одобрили без исправлений с нашей стороны.

Answer (score 2):

DEP перестала существовать, вместо нее - ABM (Apple Business Manager).

Если ваши заказчики, например, из Украины или другой европейской страны, то вариант с ABM подойдет, но только в том случае, если у заказчика мобильные устройства управляются через MDM. По-другому вы не сможете установить.

ИзменИте описание приложения так, чтобы не было понятно, что это только для конкретной компании. Или "допилите" приложение так, чтобы оно стало универсальным и подходило для всех грузчиков мира :)

Enterprise аккаунт - тоже не вариант: его в последнее время не дают никому, кроме крупных компаний, во вторых, придется приложение пересобирать и переустанавливать как минимум каждый год - Distribution Profile имеет срок годности не более года (плюс нужно учитывать срок действия сертификата, которым этот профиль был подписан). Мы использовали эту схему несколько лет, сейчас переходим на ABM.

Comment: А что значит "устройства управляются через MDM"?

Comment: Управление через MDM (Mobile Device Management) - это использовать некую платформу/систему для настройки и администрирования мобильных устройств: настраивать ограничения, устанавливать и удалять  различные профили, приложения и др. 
Есть бесплатный (условно) вариант реализации - например для яблочных устройств - Apple Profile Manager (+Apple Configurator 2), и есть много коммерческих SAAS-решений.